# Hiding sections, but keep references

Tags: text-decorations, section-titles, hide

I'd like to selectively print parts of an article.

What I want is to hide the part between the "XX", without changing anything else.

How can I do it? The following is what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myhideenv}{
  %\ifshow
    {\tiny {XX\BODY{}XX}}
  %\fi
  }

\begin{document}

The start of the report.

\begin{myhideenv}
\section{Testsection not printed} \label{testsection}

Test not printed
\end{myhideenv}

Section reference is still correct: \ref{testsection}

\section{This is section two}

It is still correct when myhideenv is hidden.

The end of the report.

\end{document}
```

[image: Printout]

Phantom (or variants) will not work since they are still making room for the text. It must not be selectable hidden text, i.e. white text on white background.

Comment: if you don't mind your sections starting a new page, you can use `\include` which does exactly that, removes sections but keeps counters and cross references

Comment: I'd like to do it by automation and use conditionals at several places in the document, so if using new pages for every there will be lots of gaps. Otherwise a solution I didn't think about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not 100% safe but...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myhideenv}{%
  \setbox0\vbox{%
   \let\xxwrite\write
   \protected\def\write{\immediate\xxwrite}%
   {\tiny XX\BODY XX}}
  }

\begin{document}

The start of the report.

\begin{myhideenv}
\section{Testsection not printed} \label{testsection}

Test not printed
\end{myhideenv}

Section reference is still correct: \ref{testsection}

\section{This is section two}

It is still correct when myhideenv is hidden.

The end of the report.

\end{document}
```

save in a discarded box and locally redefine `\write` so references are written to the aux file even though the `\label` never appears on a page.

Comment: Hope you do not mind the edit, seen the `\documentclass` line was missing :)

Comment: @JamesT ooops:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! Compiles and works in my xelatex environment.

Comment: A couple of notes: This approach seems to work with `amsthm` environments inside `myhideenv` and `cleveref` correctly references items inside. 
Macros, however, that are defined inside a `myhideenv` will not be accessible outside of it.